# GAS - Access Other User's Calendar ID

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google App for Business.

Is it possible to access other user's calendar to input & retrieve event?
I only know how to do it for my own calendar, but not others.
I have super administrator access.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get any calendar [by it's ID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarById(String)), and then just [get the events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getEvents(Date,Date)). As per your comment I don't believe that it will allow you to get any calendar in the domain, you appear to need to be subscribed. Whether this is expected or not I'm unsure.

Enter the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar), which uses the Calendar API to manage your domains calendars (and I suspect is probably the correct way to go about managing your domains calendars). After you [turn the calendar service on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced), you can do what your looking for simply like so:

```
function calendar(){
  var cal = Calendar.Calendars.get('calendar@domain');
  Logger.log(cal.summary);
};
```

Which will return the 'name' of the calendar. (Note: For primary calendars, the 'name' of the calendar is almost always the same as the calendar ID).

Comment: Thanks for the reference.
However, it seems that I'm still unable to access other user's calendar

`function test() {
 var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("user1@domain.com");
 Logger.log(calendar.getName());
}`

It returns NULL, which probably means it doesn't exist or I don't have access to it.

I have super admin access though.
I'm only able to access user1@domain.com calendar when I add it to my calendar.

Comment: I've updated a more helpful response, now that it's clearer what the issue is.

Comment: I've tried. Seems like I need to be subscribed, otherwise it wouldn't work. Thanks for the help nevertheless :)

Comment: It works for me for all calendars. Subscribed or not.

Comment: It works with no subscription to the calendar, AND also even if you are not a domain admin. To get events from calendars you have permissions to read (in JS) `Calendar.Events.list("email@domain.com", arguments);` where `var arguments = { timeMin: timeMin, timeMax: timeMax }` for example.