# Can I set a variable to be an "Id" for a .getCalendarById in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

So I want a google spreadsheet to take data from a calendar with two tabs. One tab will be where the data is inputted; "ss.". The second tab will be a settings tab where you can select the DateFrom, DateTo and CurrentEmail; "ssSettings". When the user enters the dates to and from, they can also see what email the script is currently getting its information from and they can change it if they want. I set the variable for "datefrom" and "dateto" but when I try to do the same for the "currentEmail" i get the following error;

```
TypeError: Cannot call method "getEvents" of null. (line 8, file "Code")
```

anyone know how to solve this? Im fairly new to google script. This is my script;

```js
    function getEvents() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GettingEvents")
      var ssSettings = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GettingEventsSettings");
      var DateFrom = ssSettings.getRange("B1").getValue();
      var DateTo = ssSettings.getRange("B2").getValue();
      var CurrentEmail = ssSettings.getRange("B3").getValue();
      var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CurrentEmail);
      var events = cal.getEvents(DateFrom, DateTo);
      var lr = ss.getLastRow();
      ss.getRange(2, 1, lr, 5).clearContent();
      for(var i = 0;i<events.length;i++){
         var title = events[i].getTitle();
         var sd = events[i].getStartTime();
         var ed = events[i].getEndTime();
         var loc = events[i].getLocation();
         var des = events[i].getDescription();

         ss.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(title);
         ss.getRange(i+2,2).setValue(sd);
         ss.getRange(i+2,3).setValue(ed);
         ss.getRange(i+2,4).setValue(loc);
         ss.getRange(i+2,5).setValue(des);
      }
    }
```

I'd like the settings tab to look like this, or something that can be edited by the user without screwing with the code.

[image]

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27503943/10713297) helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the `TypeError: Cannot call method "getEvents" of null. (line 8, file "Code")` is because the script you are using is **not** bound to the active spreadsheet. The `.getActive()` method returns the currently active spreadsheet, or `null` if there is none, which happened in your case in the code provided above.

In order to be able to interact with the Spreadsheet, you have to update your code to this:

```js
var as = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID");
var ss = as.getSheetByName("GettingEvents")
var ssSettings = as.getSheetByName("GettingEventsSettings");
```

The `.openById()` method opens the Spreadsheet with the specified id and therefore you can get the sheets by their name.

Furthermore, I suggest you take a look at these links since they might be of help in your future development:

1. [Class SpreadsheetApp - openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid);
2. [Class SpreadsheetApp - getActive()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive).

Comment: Thanks for your advice but im receiving the same error; `Cannot call method "getEvents" of null.` my intuition is that I am not creating my "CurrentEmail" variable correctly and it must require more than just `ssSettings.getRange("B3").getValue();`

Comment: Hello @Mauricio, thank you for your reply. How does the `email` variable look like? Because I tried your code and there was no issue with that, so you might want to take a look into that. Cheers!

Comment: did I enter it correctly?

`function getEvents() {
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var ss = as.getSheetByName("GettingEvents")
  var ssSettings = as.getSheetByName("GettingEventsSettings");
      var DateFrom = ssSettings.getRange("B1").getValue();
      var DateTo = ssSettings.getRange("B2").getValue();
      var CurrentEmail = ssSettings.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(CurrentEmail);
  var events = cal.getEvents(DateFrom, DateTo);.....`

Comment: The problem is not in the code, because it works fine. You might want to check **how the email address is declared** in the `GettingEventsSettings` sheet. Does the email address exist and moreover, are there any `calendars` associated with it?

Comment: works perfect! I guess the email I was using needed permissions from a different account. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this get the info on all of your calendars:

```
function calinfo() {
  var cals=CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var calObj={nameA:[]};
  cals.forEach(function(cal,i){calObj[cal.getName()]=cal.getId();calObj.nameA.push(cal.getName());});
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(calObj));
}
```